# NestJS Dependency Injection with Constructor parameters in injected dependency

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, jestjs, nestjs

I am struggling in NestJS with the Dependency Injection, for a service, that is injected into another service, that is then used by a controller.

```
Controller
    - ReturnResults <- Injected Service to get data from multiple sources
        - FileSystemReader <- Injected Service into ReturnResults. Needs
             - Configuration    <- NestJS Configuration service to return .env values
```

The problem I have is passing a constructor variable to the FileSystemReader service, from the ReturnResults service.  FileSystemReader(Configuration, string) is a commn function used to provide file system access to many modules.  The string parameter is the environment setting to get, which typically is used to specify the .env parameter, for a setting to point to the files, as the different modules read different files from the file system and different paths.

The FileSystemReader class works, has testing, etc.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

private Directory_:string;

@Injectable()
export class FileSystemReaderService {
    /**
     *
     * @param Configuration - ConfigService Configuration service to read the .env file
     */
    constructor(
        private readonly Configuration_:ConfigService,
        @Inject('ENV_VARIABLE') private readonly EnvPathVarName:string
    )
    {
         this.Directory_ = this.Configuration.get<string>(EnvPathVarName, './');
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The test file can then pass the variable by injecting the ENV_VARIABLE:

```
describe('FileReaderService', () => {
    let service: FileSystemReaderService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [ ConfigModule ],
            providers: [
                ConfigService,
                { provide: 'ENV_VARIABLE', useValue: 'FILES'},
                FileSystemReaderService
            ]
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<FileSystemReaderService>(FileSystemReaderService);
    });
    ...
});
```

My problem arises now, when I use the FileSystemReaderService, injected in to my ReturnResults service.

The typical constructor would then be:

```
constructor(
    private Configuration:ConfigService,
    @Inject('FILESYSTEM') private readonly FileSystem:FileSystemReaderService
    // This is done for the ReturnResults service to use the mock class, as I do not need to test this directly at this level.
)
```

I do not know how to set the variable to have the FileSystem class use it. Without dependency injection, it would be

```
    const FileSystemRS:FileSystemReaderService = new FileSystemReaderService(Configuration, 'FILES');
```

I do not know how to do this in the header of the constructor.

Comment: I'm trying to fully understand the issue. Is the problem you want `FileSystemReader` service to receive different parameter values based on who is the parent service?

Comment: No.  I wanted the FileSystemReader to be able to take a parameter from the configuration, that would be passed by the Parent service.  FileSystemReader was a common service, and it loaded a base directory (FILES=/src/dir/) from the .env, using a parameter (FILES).  Once I was re-using this for other functions, I wanted to be able to pass the variable name (TESTS) and use a different path.  What I have ended up doing for now, is remove the ConfigurationService and .env, and simply have the parent service pass the path to use.  However, I still have the same issue if I need to pass a variable.

Comment: More than a year ago, have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: @buryo Not directly.  I changed how I did this in my code.  I injected the FileSystemService as any dependency would be injected.  Then used the methods internally, to accept the path.  Since I was specifying the path, the service using FileSystemService, would read the configuration (.env), get the default path, and simply provide that with the extra path I wanted, to the service as one long, full path.